# (VBA-PPT) Redim error 9? Index out of bounds

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I dont get it - i have an array in a different module, which holds the data and is initialised at start with standard values.

When i try to use daten.getWasserTemp() it seems not deliver a array everytime. Arraysize incoming is always 5.

The line with vWate(1) throws an array out of bounds error 9. (line 5)

**EDIT:**
The data is saved in module daten.
It gets initialised when the slide (slide30) is first opened with method daten.reset()

Thanks!

Can you help me? I am blind.. Thanks!

Module Logik:

```
Dim vTemp As Double
Dim vWate() As Double
ReDim vWate(5)
vWate = daten.getWasserTemp    
If vWate(1) <= 0 Then vTemp = 0
```

Module Daten:

```
Dim vWasserTemp() As Double
```

....

```
Function getWasserTemp() As Double()
getWasserTemp = vWasserTemp                 
End Function
```

...

```
sub reset ()
vWasserTemp(1) = 15
vWasserTemp(2) = 14
vWasserTemp(3) = 5
vWasserTemp(4) = 4
end sub
```

Module Slide30:

```
Sub OnSlideShowPageChange()
daten.reset
End Sub
```

Comment: If daten.getWasserTemp returns an array then ReDim vWate(5) does nothing. You need to show the code for daten.getWasserTemp.

Comment: Edited :) Can you have a look again? Thanks!

Comment: In your reset function do the following: Redim vWasserTemp(0 to 3)  then, vWasserTemp(0) = 15, ...(1) =14, … (2) = 5, …(3) = 4. make sure to start your arrays at zero.  Also, if you are trying to access vWasserTemp outside of daten then, you need to declare it as public ( Ex: `Public vWasserTemp() as double`. That may help.

Comment: I concur with IamNerd. I just finished my tests and got an error when trying to run `reset` because the size of the array was not set. Also, arrays start with 0, not 1, which is why that other comment advises assigning starting with 0.

Comment: You need to always declare `Option Explicit` as the first line in every code page. this helps you to find errors.

Comment: Note: for future questions please provide code that can be used "as is". I had to modify your code in order to run and test it. Refer to [mcve] for moreinformation.

Comment: Function getWasserTemp() As Double() should be Function getWasserTemp() As Variant.   Cindy's correct that Dim vWate() As Double will give you a 0-based array, but if for some reason you prefer 1-based arrays, you can do e.g. Dim vWate(1 to 5) As Double, or include Option Base 1 at the top of the module where you Dim the array, in which case Dim vWate() As Double gives you a 1-based array.